# How to re-bind jQuery window scroll again after unbinding it?

Tags: jquery, scroll, bind, unbind

I need to re `bind()` the `scroll()` to `$(window)` again after using `unbind()` to stop a div replicating itself - `(#mystat-1)`. I have tried `$(window).bind('scroll');` but it doesn't work. Thanks!

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($("#moreSection").visible(true)) {
        doActionAndStopScript();
    }
});

function doActionAndStopScript() {
    $('#myStat-1').circliful() // now it will fire once
    $(window).unbind('scroll');
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For this scenario I would recommed you to use [event.namespace](https://api.jquery.com/event.namespace/). I would also recommend you to use [`$.fn.on()`](https://api.jquery.com/on/) and [`$.fn.off()`](https://api.jquery.com/off/)

*Code is self explanatory.*

```
//Declare a event hanlder
function scrollHandler(){
    if ($("#moreSection").visible(true)){
        doActionAndStopScript();

        //Bind event
        $(window).on('scroll.test', scrollHandler);
    }
}

function doActionAndStopScript(){
    // now it will fire once
    $('#myStat-1').circliful();

    //Unbind it
    $(window).off('scroll.test');
}

//Bind event
$(window).on('scroll.test', scrollHandler);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can bind the `event` again in your `doActionAndStopScript` function.

```
function scrollHandler() {
       if ($("#moreSection").visible(true)){
            doActionAndStopScript();
       }
}

$(window).scroll(scrollHandler);

function doActionAndStopScript(){
     $('#myStat-1').circliful();
     $(window).unbind('scroll');
 }
```

Now you can bind the event again using `$(window).bind('scroll', scrollHandler);`